# Lightswitch : can it create a real time SQLServer DB Monitoring application?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-lightswitch

Can Lightswitch Be Used To Create A Web Based Real Time SQL Server Databse Monitoring Application

In otherwords if I have one or more querys I run in SQL Server Mgt Studio's Query Tool to get various pieces of information can I use Lightswitch to create an IE based version of this that will execute the same queries against the same SQL database and re-execute those on some timed value so that I effectively have a real time montioring applictaion or live report that shows the info I choose?

SQL Server Mgt Studio has a great tool called the Activity Monitor that on a fixed interval (a value that can be changed by the user) to rquery a number of system views and other code so as to provide the user with a monitoring like interface that is effetcively a live report.  Its live because it continually re-querys the data source without the user having to do anything.

For a long time I've been using pre-defined queries in SSMS's query tool to continually check on data I've defined (as opposed as to system views created by someone at Microsoft) and I would love a way to do this without having to use SSMS and in a way so that it auto executes the queries on a specific interval so I don't have to continually press F5.

If there is another solution aside from LIghtswitch thaat can do this that doesn;t cost and arm and a leg I'd love to hear about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would need to attach the database to Lightswitch and recreate the queries there. Then create a screen to display the relevant data. But yes, Lightswitch can do what you want. You just need to implement a timer to refresh the screen on the interval you define. I do something similar in my Lightswitch app. I followed this guide:

http://lightswitchspecial.blogspot.in/2012/02/autorefresh-lightswitch-screen.html